# ExpectedException.expect not working. junit

Tags: java, junit

Following is my code.

```
@Rule
private ExpectedException m_exception = ExpectedException.none();



@Test
public void testDecode()
{   
    m_exception.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();

}
```

When I run this test, It fails,

```
[junit] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[junit]     at com.sonicsw.mf.framework.util.test.URLUtilityTest.testDecode(URLUtilityTest.java:60)
[junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
[junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
```

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm sure, this is not *shortest code* for demonstrating problem, because of this: `URLUtilityTest.java:60`. There is some additional code in your test which brokes whole picture

Comment: There are many other test cases in URLUtilityTest class and they are not causing any problem except for this one.

Comment: Remove all of the non-relevent test methods, bit do.include the rest of the class, including class annotations (and verify that it is still broken)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the posted stacktrace, but I think that `@Rule` annotated fields have to be `public`.

Comment: Same error with public.

Comment: @Ahmad.Masood adent's comment is absolutely right. Your code with `public` modifier for `@Rule` works fine.

Comment: I have made it public and result is same

Comment: Is the test class using a custom test-runner? Can you provide the full example? Other than the mentioned `public` modifier there is no issue with the example.

Answer (score 2):

Methods and fields annotated with `@Rule` need to be public. Also your test class shouldn't extend `junit.framework.TestCase` directly or indirectly (so the tests won't be run as JUnit3-style tests). I also recommend always annotating JUnit4-style tests with `@RunWith`

Answer (score -4):

I believe you should have annotated the test itself to tell it to expect that exception type.

Try replacing your `@Test`annotation with `@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)` and see if it works for you.

Comment: Using the annotation is the old way, using the `@Rule ExpectedException` is the new way (and it offers more specific ways to assert).